# script error: 'c is not a function"

Tags: html, javascript

I get the following javascript error when I debug in firebug:

```
'cities' is not a function.
```

What I'm trying to achieve is dynamic options and it used to work, this is just a new version of the page which has broken the old function that I need to restore. It's called from HTML:

`<select name="w" onchange="cities(this);" id="searcharea_expanded" class="">`

And it is declared as javascript in the same file:

```
<script>
function cities(obj){

    if(obj.value == '3'){

         //undisplay cities options municipality_control2

        document.getElementById('municipality_control').style.display='none'

    }else{

        $('#cities').load('/cities?regionId='+obj.value);
    }
}  
}
</script>
```

So why am I getting this error? I also have a div named cities which is the div that the script shall update and this used to work:

```
<div id="cities" class="selectbox munics ">
     <select id="municipality_control" name="m">
         <option value="4691207">Madgaon</option>
         <option value="4695203">Mormugao</option>
         <option value="4692204">Panaji</option>
         <option value="4676203">Other city</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: did you include script src = "jquery.js"?

Comment: I guess you have another script somewhere that overrides the cities. Something like: var cities = "aa";

Comment: Enter "cities" (without quotes) in the Firebug console.  Show the value here.

Comment: Don't have function and DOM element with the same name/ID. It might work but it might just as well cause weird problems. Change either the function name or the div id.

Comment: [He closes more braces that he opened!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131742/1420197)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - Binding a function to an Event to an element returns an error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882836/javascript-binding-a-function-to-an-event-to-an-element-returns-an-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are closing more braces than you've opened.
If you use jQuery, use its functions. For example instead of `document.getElementById("id")` use `$("#id")`.

Your code will be:

```
<script>
    function cities(obj){
       if(obj.val() == '3'){
         // undisplay cities options municipality_control2
         // document.getElementById('municipality_control').style.display='none'
         $('#municipality_control').hide()
       } else {
         $('#cities').load('/cities?regionId='+obj.val());
       }
    }  
    // } << This has to be removed
</script>
```

I also recommend you to prevent using HTML attributes for Javascript like `onchange="..."`. Use the following, instead:

```
$("#searcharea_expanded").on("change", function () {
     cities($(this));
});
```

Comment: This could be a problem (if it is not just a typo in the question), but even this fix won't solve the issue. The OP has an element with the ID `cities`. This will create a global variable `cities` referencing the DOM element. The function declaration will be ignored (or whatever the browser does in this case).

Comment: No, if you have a DOM element with the id `test` and a function named `test` you will can call the function. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/msJHm/)

Comment: In your demo you are defining `test` inside the `load` event handler, so it is not global but local. Of course that will work. But I also cannot reproduce my claim using a global function called form an inline event handler, so maybe this was fixed in newer browser builds. It was a problem until not long ago though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that's a direct copy+paste from your site, then the problem is easy: you have an extra closing brace `}` at the end of the script. This is a syntax error that will make the entire script block invalid, which means that the function will never be defined.

if you indent your code properly, you'd notice this kind of thing more easily. In addition, I recommend using a decent editor or IDE to write your code, which does syntax highlighting. For example, opening your code in Netbeans immediately puts an error marker on the relevant line, making it extremely easy to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three possibilities that I can see:

- Your `cities()` function gets called (maybe because you `change` the `select`) before the script that defines it is interpreted. Verify that the `<script>` opens and closes before the HTML. Possibly, add the `onchange` listener via jQuery instead of inlining it.
- There's an error in the Javascript preventing the `cities` declaration from being executed at all. Inspect the error console or Javascript console or whatever your browser supplies to intercept Javascript errors.
- Your `cities` objects gets overwritten somehow by another `cities` (possibly holding the jQuery handle to the `cities` `div`?).

I ordered the possibilities in decreasing order of likelihood based on *my* own mistakes.